# How do I change my code using Matplotlib to stop the DepreciatonWarning : Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

When I use the function fig.add_subplot() from Matplotlib I get a warning

"Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working"

I can see where its coming from in the collections module when it is called by matplotlib.cbook in the line:

if isinstance(obj, collections.Iterator):

But I have no idea how to change my code to avoid this problem without changing the code in matplotlib

The line in my code creating the warning is add_subplot below:

nrows = 2

ncols = 1

outer_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows, ncols, figure = fig, wspace = 0.13, hspace = .16)

inner_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(irows,1,subplot_spec=outer_grid[1], hspace=0.0,height_ratios = hratios)

fig.add_subplot(inner_grid[0])

Comment: Somehow this sounds like your matplotlib version is too old compared to your python version.

Comment: Thank you!  I should have checked that, school boy error.   I thought i was on the most recent version but had to reinstall a few weeks ago and that got missed.  Much appreciated, sorry for the obvious.